# Android button in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hi, developers

As you can see the picture above, I am trying to move the face icon to a bit left so that I can see the whole face. However, in RelativelyLayout, I have not found how. Can anyone let me know how to do it? Thanks.

The following is my xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainCtrlLayout" 
android:background="@drawable/photo_bg" 
android:layout_width="1280px" 
android:layout_height="800px">


<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="47px" 
android:id="@+id/topBarLayout"    
/>

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topBarLayout"
android:layout_marginLeft="17px" 
android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
android:background="@drawable/adv_search_btn" 
android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/strFrom" 
android:id="@+id/txtFrom" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="#FF00FFFF" 
android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
android:textSize="20px" 
android:layout_marginTop="10px">
</TextView>

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Teblate"
android:id="@+id/txtSourcePath" 
android:textColor="#FF00FFFF" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtFrom" 
android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
android:textSize="20px" 
android:layout_marginTop="10px"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/refreshBtn" 
android:background="@drawable/adv_refresh_btn" 
android:layout_below="@+id/topBarLayout"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

>
</Button>

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/layout_a1_vsview"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_below="@+id/refreshBtn" 
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:layout_height="625px" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <com.iid.dlna.activity.DMRList
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />      
</ScrollView>

<TextView
android:textColor="@color/TextCtlScreenBlue"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="24px"
android:id="@+id/a3"
android:layout_below="@+id/topBarLayout"
android:layout_height="51px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="545px" 
android:layout_width="246px">
</TextView>    

<TextView
android:textColor="@color/TextCtlScreenBlue"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="24px"
android:id="@+id/sortDateBtn"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sortPhotoBtn"
android:layout_below="@+id/topBarLayout"
android:layout_height="51px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="30px" 
android:layout_width="246px">
</TextView>

<TextView 
android:textColor="@color/TextCtlScreenBlue"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="24px"
android:id="@+id/sortAlbumBtn" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sortDateBtn" 
android:layout_below="@+id/topBarLayout" 
android:layout_height="51px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="30px" 
android:layout_width="246px">
</TextView>

<Button
android:layout_width="120px" 
android:layout_height="50px" 
android:id="@+id/photoBackBtn"
android:background="@drawable/photo_back_default"
android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_b2w"
android:textSize="24px"
android:paddingLeft="16px"
android:text="@string/ctlscreen_txt_back"
android:layout_marginLeft="500px"
android:layout_marginTop="117px" 
android:visibility="visible"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/selectAllBtn"
android:text="@string/ctlscreen_txt_selectall"
android:paddingLeft="32px"
android:textSize="24px"
android:background="@drawable/photo_selectall_default"
android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_b2w"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photoBackBtn"    
android:layout_marginTop="117px"
android:layout_marginLeft="170px"      
android:layout_width="175px"
android:layout_height="50px"/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/unselectAllBtn"
android:text="@string/ctlscreen_txt_unselectall"
android:paddingLeft="32px"
android:textSize="24px"
android:background="@drawable/photo_unselectall_default"
android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_b2w"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectAllBtn"    
android:layout_marginLeft="20px" 
android:layout_marginTop="117px" 
android:layout_width="205px"
android:layout_height="50px"/>

<Button
android:text="@string/strPrevPage"
android:id="@+id/prevBtn"
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:background="@drawable/adv_page_btn"  
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/unselectAllBtn" 
android:textSize="26px"
android:layout_marginLeft="30px"      
android:layout_marginTop="117px" 
android:layout_height="43px" 
android:layout_width="43px"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/txtPage"
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:text="00" 
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prevBtn"
android:textSize="26px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
android:layout_marginTop="117px"/>

<Button
android:text="@string/strNextPage"
android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:background="@drawable/adv_page_btn"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtPage" 
android:textSize="26px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
android:layout_marginTop="117px" 
android:layout_height="43px" 
android:layout_width="43px"/>



<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/contentListLayout"
android:layout_marginTop="189px" 
android:layout_height="544px" 
android:layout_marginLeft="507px">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/layout_contentlist_vsview" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <com.iid.dlna.activity.ContentList
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_hsview_Ver_scrolla"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/progress" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <ImageView 
    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    android:layout_height="15px" 
    android:src="@drawable/loadbar_bg" 
    android:id="@+id/iv_pro_bg" 
    android:layout_width="361px">
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView 
    android:scaleType="fitXY" 
    android:layout_height="15px" 
    android:src="@drawable/loadbar_fg" 
    android:id="@+id/iv_pro_fg" 
    android:layout_width="0px">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried the code but it still doesnt work. Did I make any mistake on my layout? The application runs on 9 inch tablet with 1280*800 resolution.

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Setting the layout-width to constant values is not a good idea. Change them to match-parent. And if you have to set values use dp instead of px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainCtrlLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/photo_bg" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refreshBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topBarLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/refreshBtn" >

</Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

what you need to do is set `android:layout_alignParentRight` to `true` on the `refreshButton`